# Why there is no external addon/extension for internet explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Why there was no extenal[third party] addons/extensions for internet explorer?is it there any technical reason behind it or it was just a microsoft glitch to prevent opensource stuff?

what were the technical stuff which prevents from installing third party addin/extensions like chrome and firefox?

in chrome we got extensions and for firefox we got addons,why not for ie?any reason for not allowing ie with extensions/addons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question cannot be answered by anyone.

The reason is simple, there ARE external third party addons available for Internet Explorer.

The only difference is that Internet Explorer does not promote them with a fancy app-store kind of thingy. But for example Ad-block plus and Last Pass can both be installed into Internet Explorer. A setup can be found on both homepages of these plugins.